# Spring oauth2 Authorization provider

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

> I am new to Oauth, I have application with Spring Oauth2 with xml
>   configuration. Have taken reference from
>   `http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/10/spring-security-oauth2-integration.html`

So the URL below to get the token is

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringRestSecurityOauth/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&username=beingjavaguys&password=spring@java
```

It gives the token reseponse.
So here in request url the `client_id` is hardcoded inside xml file.And I want to send the clientId,grantType at run time.
What things need to be taken care of here.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would send the client_id/client_secret in a header.

OAuth2 is only secure if https is used as there are secret data transmitted.

Here an example (angularjs):

```
    auth = 'Basic ' + window.btoa(client_id + ':' + client_secret);
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = auth;
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    grantparam= 'grant_type=password&username='+loginData.username +   '&password=' + loginData.password;
    $http.post('https://localhost:8123/oauth/token?'+grantparam)
```

here in curl from postman:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Basic 111111111111111" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 11111111-111111111111111" "https://localhost:8443/sf/api/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=11111111111&password=**********"
```